# CSRF validation with web services with android app

Tags: android, security, post, yii, csrf

I have created a web service which is fully working. However, as soon as I enable CSRF validation in config/main.php I get an error when trying to use the web service saying:

> The CSRF token could not be verified.

Instead of skipping the CSRF token validation, Is there any other solution to this?

Is there a way to actually validate the CSRF Token Successfully when using web-services via Android App?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on multiple things not mentioned in the question.

The first question is how authentication works in the services. If it is something that a client browser will not send automatically (ie. not cookie-based, but for example tokens added to request headers), the services are not vulnerable to CSRF and you can turn off csrf protection.

If it uses cookies (probably not the best for services most of the time), then you need to protect it against CSRF. As for how, it depends on what protection is implemented. If it's the standard [synchronizer token pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens), then you need to first download a page via GET, extract the token and send it back in the appropriate field in subsequent POST/PUT/DELETE requests. This would look awkward in a mobile app, you would be better off changing the API to token-based auth instead. :) If it's something like [double posting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie), you might be able to craft a double-posted token that is accepted in the services. If it's something else, you need to understand how the protection works and find out how to actually pass the right things to the services.

As a sidenote, it's not only cookie-based authentication that might be vulnerable to CSRF. For example if the API uses HTTP basic auth, that too is cached by a browser and sent automatically, and as such it is vulnerable to CSRF if a user ever enters credentials directly into the browser (but that is a strange usecase which reduces the risk). Also client certificates are sent automatically by the browser and can similarly be vulnerable to CSRF.

So to sum it up (and a bit simplified, see above for details):

1. Is authentication on services cookie-based?

   - No -> remove CSRF protection, it's not vulnerable (but see exceptions above), done.
   - Yes -> 2.
2. Can you change authentication to token-based (with the token being sent in request headers)?

   - Yes -> Change it, done.
   - No -> 3.
3. What is the method for CSRF protection?

   - Synchronizer token pattern -> you need to get a page to get the token to use
   - Double posting -> depending on the implementation you may be able to double post an appropriate value in a cookie and a header
   - Something else -> Find out how protection works and how you can send the right token

Also be aware that if CORS is enabled on the services (not needed for the mobile app), that complicates things a bit in terms of CSRF, but that's an orthogonal problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!!
My authentication services are not cookie-based, so I removed the CSRF protection.
But Now with every new request, it is sending a new session Id, because of that my cart not showing any product in it. when someone adds a product into the cart, it is with some session_id(sess_4qc418amqa6g69uicosu0jsou6), but on cart page. it says zero products as session_id( sess_5mcj87a15b39o1r8fm9tp8gkl6) on cart page is changed. I m using yii1.1.17.

Comment: It Looks like there's some other issue with server's session handling, when i call the web service from a web browser or postman, it is working as expected, but when i am using the web service from android app, server is treating every request as a new user, hence creating new session every time. 
Not sure what's causing the issue, same app is working fine on a different server.